# Is there a way to make Links toward to the/p/example.html using the/p/+ Data:blog.searchLabel?

Tags: blogger

I was really dizzy looking for ways to make Links Toward to the/p/contoh.html using the/p/+ Data:blog.searchLabel

Answer (score 0):

To create dynamic links using `<data:blog.searchLabel/>` layout tag, the code will look like -

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>
<a expr:href='&quot;http://yourblog.com/p/&quot; + data:blog.searchLabel + &quot;.html&quot;' >Link To Page</a>
</b:if>
```

This has been wrapped with a conditional statement so that no broken links are generated (aka when `<data:blog.searchLabel/>` is empty). Include this code only in the Template > Edit HTML section.

This only displays links when any label page is opened (URL of the type `myblog.com/search/label/LabelName`)

In case you want to target search queries (URL of the type `myblog.com/search?q=SearchQuery` ) then instead use the layout tag `data:blog.searchQuery`